# Inequalities for the solution of $x = (x-a) e^{x+a}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, upper-lower-bounds, elementary-functions, nonlinear-analysis

Let $a > 0$. The equation
$$(x-a) \, e^{x+a} = x $$
must be solved for $x > 0$. Since the solution does not have a closed form, I would like to obtain bounds for the solution.

Until now, I was able to show that $$ a < x < \sqrt{a}\sqrt{a + 1}. $$

The lower bound comes from $(x-a) e^{x+a} = x > 0$ and the upper bound comes from $e^{x+a} > 1+x+a$.

I'm interested in any better bounds than the ones I provided. However, to keep the question objective, I'm interested in the proof of the better upper bound $$x < \sqrt{a}\sqrt{a+e^{-a}},$$ which is very tight. I have tried to compare derivatives and use other inequalities but to no avail.

---

I also obtained the power series
$$ x =\sqrt{a} - \frac{a}{4} + \frac{31 a^{3/2}}{96} +\frac{a^2}{16} - \frac{229 a^{5/2}}{92160} + \frac{a^3}{320} + \mathcal{O}(a^{7/2})$$
as $a \to 0^+$ for the solution; however, I'm after a simple bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to solve for $x$ the equation $$x = (x-a)\, e^{(x+a)}$$ means that you are looking for the inverse of
$$a=W\left(-x\,e^{-2 x}\right)+x \quad \text{for} \quad x>0\quad \text{and} \quad a>0 \tag 1$$

Consider the function
$$f(x)=x -(x-a)\, e^{(x+a)}$$ Its first derivative cancels at
$$x_*=W\left(e^{1-2 a}\right)+a-1$$ The second derivative test shows that this is a maximum. So, the solution is $x > x_*$.

Using Taylor series, we have
$$f(x)=f(x_*)+\frac 12 f''(x_*)(x-x_*)^2+O\left((x-x_*)^3\right)$$ which gives a first estimate
$$x_1=x_*+\sqrt{-2\frac{f(x_*)}{f''(x_*)}}$$

By Darboux theorem, we know that $x_1$ is an overestimate of the solution which will be reached without any overshoot using Newton method.

Similarly, $x=a$ is an underestimate of the solution.

Suppose that we make a series expansion around $x=a$

$$f(x)=a-\left(e^{2 a}-1\right)(x-a)-e^{2 a} \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac {(x-a)^n}{(n-1)!}$$
Truncating to some low order, using power series reversion.  gives
$$x=a+\frac a {t-1}-\frac{a^2 t}{(t-1)^3}+\frac{a^3 t (3 t+1)}{2 (t-1)^5}+\cdots \tag 2$$$$ where $t=e^{2a}$.

This is again an overestimate of the solution.

Trying $(2)$ for a few values of $a$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 1.00 & 1.136225395 &  1.134220030 \\
 1.25 & 1.350723894 &  1.350262505 \\
 1.50 & 1.572912849 &  1.572806865 \\
 1.75 & 1.801689832 &  1.801666058 \\
 2.00 & 2.035977718 &  2.035972557 \\
 2.25 & 2.274654840 &  2.274653759 \\
 2.50 & 2.516677007 &  2.516676788 \\
 2.75 & 2.761159048 &  2.761159005 \\
 3.00 & 3.007399649 &  3.007399641 \\
 3.25 & 3.254869728 &  3.254869728 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

We could do much better at the price of more terms in the initial series before truncation.

**Edit**

It seems that we can do better using the series expansion of $(1)$ around $x=a$ and making it the simplest $[1,1]$ padé approximant of it.

This would lead to a linear equation whose solution write
$$x=a + 2a \frac{\alpha_0+\alpha_1 \,a}{\beta_0+\beta_1 \,a+\beta_2 \,a^2}$$ where
$$\alpha_0=- w^2 (w+1)^2 \qquad \qquad \alpha_1=(w-1) w (w+1)^2$$

$$\beta_0=w^2\left(w^2+4 w+2\right)\qquad  \beta_1=-4w\left( w^2-w-1\right)$$
$$\beta_2=2\left(w^3-w^2-w+1\right)$$
with
$$w=W\left(-a e^{-2 a}\right)$$

Repeating the same calculations as above, there is a significant improvement for the small values of $a$.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 1.00 & 1.134027194 &  1.134220027 \\
 1.25 & 1.350252492 &  1.350262505 \\
 1.50 & 1.572811420 &  1.572806865 \\
 1.75 & 1.801668349 &  1.801666058 \\
 2.00 & 2.035973280 &  2.035972557 \\
 2.25 & 2.274653949 &  2.274653759 \\
 2.50 & 2.516676833 &  2.516676788 \\
 2.75 & 2.761159015 &  2.761159005 \\
 3.00 & 3.007399643 &  3.007399643 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

With  regard to the problem of
$$x < \sqrt{a}\sqrt{a+e^{-a}}= b$$
we have
$$f(b) <0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad f(b)\times f''(b) >0$$ So, by Darboux theorem, it is true.

Comment: Plot of a as a function of x. https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwtykEKwyAQQNG9p5ilpgba7L1E6K4UmSSjCBpltK3Hr5TuHvzvwECHC0RMG3GzHzl3mIB6kfMydaWEH4fD2uyOMeIWSToNb%2DRqHv2p4cgJw2nWVYnB8V41LKLE3KT%5FVQ2ewxHDSdXc%2DUUaHGOiv7EW2ptlbCGbmxJfndgt4Q==&lang=sage

Comment: @PM2Ring. Thank you ! Being blind, I never produce any plot being afraid that they could not be very decent. Cheers :-)

Comment: My pleasure, Claude!